# Maya API/ PySide2 , wrong argument in wrapInstance

Tags: python, api, pyqt, pyside, maya

Trying to learn some PySide2 for Maya, but there is no clear documentation for PySide2 yet, so after searching in internet coming here again for help...

I will go straight to the problem -

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
import shiboken2

def getMayaWindow():
    pointer  = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if pointer is not None:
        return shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(pointer), QtWidgets)
```

Error: TypeError: file  line 9: 'wrapInstance' called with wrong argument types:

wrapInstance(long, module)

Supported signatures:

wrapInstance(size_t, PyType) #

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to import modules by the following way:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from PySide2.QtCore import * 
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui

try:
    from shiboken import wrapInstance
except:
    from shiboken2 import wrapInstance


def getMayaWindow():    
    pointer = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if pointer is not None:
        return shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(pointer), QWidget)

getMayaWindow()
```

Comment: I don't know why my way didn't work , but your way... it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It doesn't work your way because you should write : shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(pointer), QtWidgets.QWidget())

Comment: You really should avoid using `import *` from polluting the scope's environment. Also there's no reason for the try except. If you already know you're using PySide2 then just import shiboken2. Vladlen, you almost had it. You just needed to change the last line to `QtWidgets.QWidget`. Well done for the answer, but -1 for teaching bad habits.